# Scraping and creating new df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm basically trying to create a dataframe using the following code.

Here is the resulting table I’m trying to achieve:
[image: Table]

```py
info_list = []
data_list = []
mini_exc = ['CLFAR', 'CLFLE', 'CLHOL', 'CLCAN', 'CLCLE']

for exc in mini_exc:
    grab_page = requests.get(f"http://availability.samknows.com/broadband/exchange/{exc}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(grab_page.content, 'html.parser')
    warning = soup.findAll('div', class_='item-content')

    for x in warning:
        for y in x.findAll('th'):
            info_list.append(y.text)

        for z in x.findAll('td'):
            data_list.append(z.text)
```

Basically, I would like to have a dataframe with the elements in info list as column names and `data_list` as rows corresponding to the correspondent columns.

As you can see I obtained a dataframe with correct info data, but I could not add the new columns. I know that:

```py
for y in x.findAll('th'):
    info_list.append(y.text)
```

should be outside the loop because I just need it once, but I put it there so you could get the column names.

Comment: Can you add how you create the DataFrame afterwards? I think it would help

Answer (score 0):

That'what I did in the end guys, I created a Dataframe from a list with the info values I needed and after I run this code:

"""

for exc in ['CLFAR', 'CLFLE', 'CLHOL', 'CLCAN', 'CLCLE']:

```
info_list = []
grab_page = requests.get(f"http://availability.samknows.com/broadband/exchange/{exc}")
soup = BeautifulSoup(grab_page.content, 'html.parser')
warning = soup.findAll('div', class_='item-content')

for x in warning:
    for z in x.findAll('td'):
        info_list.append(z.text)

exch_only_serv[exc] = info_list
```

"""

So all the time was creating a list with the values for the following code and creating a new column with it.